# compute session duration on an e-commerce dataset python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I work on an *e-commerce* dataset in `python pandas` like this:

```
Timestamp                 
2019-10-23 08:18:14 UTC     
2019-10-23 08:18:17 UTC     
2019-10-23 08:18:27 UTC     
2019-10-15 04:09:18 UTC     
2019-10-15 04:10:14 UTC 

SessionId
1
1
1
2
2
```

I would like to calculate each session duration and create a new data frame with that info.
How can I do that with pandas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of how you might do this:

```
import pandas as pd

# dummy data
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Timestamp': ['2019-10-23 08:18:14', ' 2019-10-23 08:18:17', ' 2019-10-23 08:18:27', ' 2019-10-15 04:09:18', ' 2019-10-15 04:10:14'],
    'SessionId': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2]
})
df.Timestamp = pd.to_datetime(df.Timestamp)  # ensure timestamps are actual datetime objects

df.groupby('SessionId')['Timestamp'].agg(lambda x: max(x) - min(x)).to_frame().rename(columns={'Timestamp': 'Duration'})
```